# How to use SUBSTR in update query

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, substring

I have following update query in working_hour column time is coming **+000000000 01:14:00.771000000** this format but i want to show time 01:14:00 format only for that try to use SUBSTR but it is giving me ORA-00927: missing equal sign error 
here is my query

```
UPDATE  EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME T1 SET SUBSTR(T1.WORKING_HOUR,12,8)=
(SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP (TO_CHAR(TIME_OUT))- TO_TIMESTAMP (TO_CHAR(TIME_IN)) AS WORKING_HOUR 
FROM EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME T2 WHERE TRUNC(PUNCH_DATE)=TRUNC(SYSDATE)) WHERE T1.EMPLOYEE_ID='73584' AND TRUNC(T1.PUNCH_DATE)=TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

my table structure is as follow:

```
TIME_IN         TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE
TIME_OUT            TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE
WORKING_HOUR        VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
PUNCH_DATE          DATE
TIME_OUT_HISTORY    VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)
```

Comment: You have to assign to a _column_ alone. E.g. `... SET WORKING_HOUR = ...`

Comment: UPDATE  EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME T1 SET T1.WORKING_HOUR=SUBSTR(T1.WORKING_HOUR,12,8)
(SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP (TO_CHAR(TIME_OUT))- TO_TIMESTAMP (TO_CHAR(TIME_IN)) AS WORKING_HOUR 
FROM EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME T2 WHERE TRUNC(PUNCH_DATE)=TRUNC(SYSDATE)) WHERE T1.EMPLOYEE_ID='73584' AND TRUNC(T1.PUNCH_DATE)=TRUNC(SYSDATE)

i done above but giving me SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: The statement looks weird. Why do you invoke `to_char` on your datetime columns only to apply `to_timestamp` then? Why not simply `time_out - time_in`? Then in your subquery you select all records with punch_date = today, no matter which employee. But such subquery in an update statement should return exactly one row. Please explain and show some sample records and expected results, so we get an idea what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: You are far from there. Start with a basic update. Take small steps until you're done.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: im creating one application where user can login and logout when user login that login time will be insert in database in column time_in,when logout user logout details will enter in time_out column now i want to find differnce between them that difference is coming correctly +000000000 01:14:00.771000 this format but i want 01:14:00 this format output

Comment: What is the data type of the column? Is it `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND`? If it is then this makes a huge difference to the answers compared to having a `VARCHAR2` column.

Comment: @MT0: i updated my question

Comment: You can't use `substr()` on the left side of an assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TIMESTAMP - TIMESTAMP` gives an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` result (not a string) - just add that to an epoch data and use `TO_CHAR` to get the time component:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/21f8d/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME(
  EMPLOYEE_ID         INTEGER,
  TIME_IN             TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE,
  TIME_OUT            TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE,
  WORKING_HOUR        VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  PUNCH_DATE          DATE,
  TIME_OUT_HISTORY    VARCHAR2(200 BYTE)
);

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME ( 
  EMPLOYEE_ID,
  TIME_IN,
  TIME_OUT,
  WORKING_HOUR,
  PUNCH_DATE,
  TIME_OUT_HISTORY
)
SELECT 73584,
       SYSTIMESTAMP,
       SYSTIMESTAMP + INTERVAL '+000000000 01:14:00.771000000' DAY TO SECOND,
       NULL,
       SYSDATE,
       NULL
FROM   DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
UPDATE  EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME
SET WORKING_HOUR = TO_CHAR( 
                     DATE '0001-01-01' + ( TIME_OUT- TIME_IN ),
                     'HH24:MI:SS'
                   )
WHERE  EMPLOYEE_ID= 73584
AND    PUNCH_DATE >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
AND    PUNCH_DATE <  TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,
       TO_CHAR( TIME_IN,  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6 TZR' ) AS TIME_IN,
       TO_CHAR( TIME_OUT, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6 TZR' ) AS TIME_OUT,
       WORKING_HOUR,
       PUNCH_DATE,
       TIME_OUT_HISTORY
FROM   EMPLOYEE_LOGIN_TIME;
```

**Results**:

```
| EMPLOYEE_ID |                        TIME_IN |                       TIME_OUT | WORKING_HOUR |          PUNCH_DATE | TIME_OUT_HISTORY |
|-------------|--------------------------------|--------------------------------|--------------|---------------------|------------------|
|       73584 | 2018-05-14 09:00:00.000000 PST | 2018-05-14 10:14:00.771000 PST |     01:14:00 | 2018-05-14 09:00:00 |           (null) |
```

Comment: Yes!! that's the answer i'm looking thank you @MT0 thank very very much